# Open / Close Sidebar on click

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins

I try to open / close a sidebar in a firefox plugin when I click on a button.

So to make it clear, in my plugin, I add a small icon in the side bar.
The plugin runs in a left sidebar and can be open with a shortcut (as Bookmarks).

I would like to open (if close) or close it (if open) by click on the icon.
Any suggestion on the way to do it ?

Kind regards

Comment: usually the plugin should already have it included. In any case you should post the code you are using.

Comment: Well, that's the fact, I try to create a plugin, for now I just have a empty page.html
Code is here https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/annotate-page/sidebar

Comment: A quick search on Google will give you tons of examples e.g. [link](https://codepen.io/tio-jevero-the-styleful/pen/MdZQBo)

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer my question.
I'm talking about a sidebar in Firefox and an action on the click of the icon.

Comment: By the way, I DO search on google before asking